# How to know whether the observable update/change is from View or Manual update - knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

Is there any way to know whether the ko observable is updated/changed from a View Action [click, select, focus....] or the observable is updated manually.

For example,

```
<div data-bind="hasfocus: hasFocus" />

var vm = {hasFocus: ko.observable(true)};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.hasFocus(false);
```

in this, how to know the hasFocus is updated from the view or from vm like vm.hasFocus(false);

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there is no way, but if you tell us what are trying to achieve with this, maybe there is a different solution to your problem than checking who was updated the observable...

Comment: To implement keyboard navigation i am using hasfocus binding. For example, i have a div, on focusing & pressing enter key, i should open a popup. on pressing down arrow key, i need to select something on the popup.